# Gradle dependencies: is the newest or oldest version used?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9 and I have a following line in my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader', name: 'universal-image-loader', version: '1.9.+'
```

What will be the actual version of the library used in this case? 1.9.0 or 1.9.3 (latest)?

I'm asking because I recently got a bug report in BugSense with a crash in UniversalImageLoader but the stacktrace is not relevant to the latest version (1.9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + means that it will use the latest version of the 1.9.X series, which according to Maven Central as of now: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.nostra13.universalimageloader is 1.9.3.

With the version set up like this, if 1.10.0 were to be released, you wouldn't pick it up -- that `+` symbol is only a wildcard for the third part of the version number triplet. If you wanted to get the latest version regardless, you could use:

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universalimageloader:+'
```

Note that we don't really recommend that you use the + syntax in version numbers for dependencies. For one, it will make a network request to see if there's a new version, which is a problem for a lot of developers trying to work offline. I believe it only checks once a day, but it can still be a problem. More importantly, it can cause your build to fail in unpredictable ways -- if a new version is released and it causes a compile error or bug, it can be mysterious why your build worked yesterday but started failing today.